# Add to items, with multiple occurrences

Tags: numpy

What I would like to do is something like:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 0])
i = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
n = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
a[i] += n
```

to get `a = [2, 3, 1]`. How can this operation be done (efficiently)? Let's assume that `i` may not be ordered.

*The current operation of course gives `[1, 1, 1]`, not the desired result.*

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of occurencies of each value?

Comment: @FBruzzesi No `n` can have arbitrary values.

Comment: Thanks @FBruzzesi